# What is the usual way to add static libraries to a C or C++ project?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Basic questions - I'm learning to program in C and C++. I'm not sure how to handle dependency management in these languages.

I want to add a static library to my project. What would be the usual way to state that the project needs that library, and to include the library in the project?

I'm interested in knowing how to do it in a makefile-based project (not with CMake). For what I've seen CMake allows you to automatize dependency management with the ExternalProject_Add function, but I'm interested in what would be the usual way to do it without using CMake.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You may be interested in [this QandA](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110518/binaries-in-source-control).

Comment: One thing to consider is this:  how important is it for you to be able to make changes to the code in the static library (e.g. to fix a bug or modify a feature in it)?  If you want to retain that capability, you're better off checking the library's source code into your repository and building it as part of your program's build process.

Comment: Makefile does not do package management; there's no way to specify "you must have package/library x" in it. Usually you either configure automake to check for the existence of the library or add a note in your readme saying that library x is required. I wouldn't include a compiled binary in your _source_ control.

Comment: Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo. My impression was that make did not have anything to do with package management, but as CMake seems to be able to help with thatt to some extent, I was wondering if maybe there was some way to do it in make too. I usually would not add a binary library to source control but as I'm not familiar with the C world I did not want to assume that that was not the way. I've heard about biicode by the way, it's a pity that it doesn't seem to have been adopted broadly.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner. No, I don't think I need that. My question was more about how do C programmers usually handle these kind of situations, I mean what would be the usual, common way to do it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @n.m. my question is about how a C or C++ project manages dependencies. If they are not managed automatically I am unsure, because I am starting to learn the language (as stated in my question), on what is the usual way to handle that problem in the context of those two programming languages. My impression is that there could be several ways of doing it, one would be to simply include the library in the repo, another one would be to write in the README that the project needs that library. As you see, my question is not about version control but about the usual way that this is done in C or C++

Comment: I'll edit my question to make it more understandable, I think I probably didn't phrase it very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to use the third-party library as-is, without any custom modifications on your side. My answer will also be specific to GNU/Linux but since you're writing your own `Makefile`s, I assume that this is the relevant platform for you.

While dumping the library into your repository might seem a convenient quick-fix, it is not good practice. Ideally, your repository should only contain hand-written files that your project is responsible for. This keeps a clean separation of concerns.

If your project needs libfoo, another project I'm interested in might need it too so I might decide to install libfoo on my system and use it for all projects that require it. I can do this by downloading, building and installing libfoo manually or, if I'm lucky, I can install it via my package manager. When building and installing manually, there are at least two options. I can install it system-wide or locally for my user only. On the other hand, if I think that I won't ever need libfoo again or your project requires a specific version of libfoo that is not the version I usually want to use, I might prefer to build libfoo in a local directory and not install it at all.

So to summarize, the options for your users are.

1. Install the library system-wide (eg in `/usr/lib/`) using the system's package manager.
2. Manually download, build and install the library system-wide (eg `/usr/local/lib/`).
3. Manually download, build and install the library for my local user only (eg `~/lib/`).
4. Manually download and build the library but don't install it (eg `~/src/foo-1.42/`).

The decision what option to choose should be left to your users. But while you shouldn't *impose* anything on them, you should do everything you can to *help* them.

The first thing to do with external dependencies is to document them. In your `README` file, list all dependencies of your project with the URLS to the download-pages of the respective projects. If you know that a relevant operating system has already packaged the library, also mention the name of the package people have to install for that system. All GNU/Linux distributions I know have a web-site where you can search their package index so you might want to do it for the more popular ones. If your project needs a specific version of a library, don't forget to mention this prominently.

If your users decide to go with option (1), there is nothing more to do. They will use the package manager to install the library and your `Makefile` will reference it from the `LIBS` variable (eg `-lfoo`).

If your users decide to (or have to, because the library is not packaged for their system) go with option (2) or (3), the situation isn't much different. They will download, build and install the library and once this is done, your `Makefile` will again pick it up. However, if they install the library in a non-standard location, the linker might not find it directly. Therefore, it is important that your `Makefile` uses the `LDFLAGS` variable so users can add the respective option (eg `-L${HOME}/lib/`) to it. The same goes for the include path (eg `-I${HOME}/include/`) if your code is referencing headers from the package. These options belong into the `CPPFLAGS` variable.

If your users go with option (4), they will certainly have to use a linker flag to make the library be found. For example, if libfoo is downloaded to and built in a sub-directory `foo`, they would add `-L./foo/` to `LDFLAGS`. In this case, however, you can make your user's life a little easier. Place a little shell script in your project's top-level directory that downloads and optionally configures and builds all external dependencies. Please document cleanly what actions will download stuff from the internet and make sure the user will have the last word what they want to download. Also, please have your script verify the checksums of downloaded packages before doing anything with them. Failure to do so is a potential entry point for attackers and you don't want your users to be exploited by using your software. In this case, your `Makefile` (or better, your `configure` script) should detect that the package was built locally and use that (ie add the respective `-I…` and `-L…` flags). You can also add the flags unconditionally because the pre-processor and linker will silently ignore non-existing directories.

Writing the helper script is not difficult. A simplistic version could look like this.

```sh
#! /bin/bash -eu

packages=(foo bar)
declare -A urls
urls['foo']='https://download.foo.org/foo-1.42.tar.gz'
urls['bar']='https://download.bar.org/bar-2.50.tar.gz'

cat <<'EOF' > dependency-checksums.sha1
0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33  foo-1.42.tar.gz
62cdb7020ff920e5aa642c3d4066950dd1f01f4d  bar-2.50.tar.gz
EOF

for pkg in "${packages[@]}"
do
    wget "${urls[${pkg}]}" || exit
done

sha1sum --check dependency-checksums.sha1 || {
    echo "ALERT: Verification of package integrity failed.  Stop." >&2
    exit 1
}

for pkg in "${packages[@]}"
do
    ar="${urls[${pkg}]##*/}"
    dir="${ar%.tar*}"
    tar -xf "${ar}"
    ln -s "${dir}/" "${pkg}"
    ( cd "${dir}" && ./configure && make )
done
```

You may consider polishing it a little. For example, make it understand the `--help` option and offer only downloading but not building the packages. Of course, you don't have to write a shell script. You can provide a Perl or Python script or even a Make script. In fact, it is a bad idea to use fancy Bash features as I did in the above example because many people don't use modern Bash shells.

If you're releasing your software as a source archive, there is nothing wrong with providing an *alternative* tarball that already contains all the external dependencies so your users don't have to download them individually. But you should only offer this as an alternative, not as the only option. That's for tarballs, the *repository* – as mentioned before – should be kept free of third-party stuff as much as possible.

While writing a decent “download my dependencies” script is easily doable, writing flexible `configure` scripts and `Makefile`s is tedious and you'll likely get it wrong. You should seriously consider using an automated framework for this. GNU packages usually use the GNU Autotools, namely [Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and [Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/). If you want to learn more about these tools, I can recommend John Calcote's [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593272067.do) “Autotools – A Practioner's Guide to GNU Autoconf, Automake, and Libtool”.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you so much for taking the time to write it, I appreciate it. I come from another language and that's why I am a little bit confused about some aspects of C and C++. Not having a mainstream package manager I was confused on how a C project should manage its dependecies. Adding them to the README seemed like a crude solution. I'd rather do that than prepare the bash script, though. In any case my intention is to use CMake, which for what I've read allows you to install external libraries using ExternalProject_Add. But I was curious about make.

Comment: @Gaspar You're welcome. By the way, I found it most useful to see how other popular projects (especially GNU packages) handle this but doing so takes a lot of time, of course.

Comment: Yes... I've been taking a look around and googling... but I ended a little bit confused with it all. Thanks again. I'm having a great time learning C and C++ by the way. And C++ has seen interesting additions in C++14.